# Install Oracle Instant client into Docker container for Python cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database at my company through my docker container that contains some of my python scripts with the package cx_Oracle. After i build and run the container, i get the following error:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("{0}/{1}@{2}".format(configOracle["username"], configOracle["password"],r"ed03:1521/configOracle["servername"]))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

I have an Oracle config file where the username, password, and server name are coming from and being filled in correctly. I can't seem to get it to work even after downloading the latest client from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
--TopDirectory
----instantclient
-------instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
-------instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.5.0.0.0dbru.zip
----hello_oracle.py
----Dockerfile
----requirements.txt
----configOracle.json
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.5

#Oracle Client setup
ENV ORACLE_HOME /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_5
ENV LD_RUN_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME

COPY instantclient/* /tmp/

RUN \
    mkdir -p /opt/oracle && \
    unzip "/tmp/instantclient*.zip" -d /opt/oracle && \
    ln -s $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.so.19.1 $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.so

# Working directory
WORKDIR /src
# Copying requirements.txt before entire build step
COPY requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# Installing necessary packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copying rest of files
COPY . /src
CMD ["python3", "/src/hello_oracle.py"]
```

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
pandas
numpy
matplotlib
keras
cx_Oracle
sklearn
tensorflow
pyopenssl
ndg-httpsclient
pyasn1
```

Answer (score 30):

**After many hours trying it, I finally solved it with this Dockerfile**

**Note** *I am using python 3.7, Django 3.0, Oracle Database 12c and Pipenv for package management*

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

# Installing Oracle instant client
WORKDIR    /opt/oracle
RUN        apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip \
            && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
            && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci \
            && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
            && ldconfig

WORKDIR    /app
COPY       . .  # Copy my project folder content into /app container directory
RUN        pip3 install pipenv
RUN        pipenv install
EXPOSE     8000
# For this statement to work you need to add the next two lines into Pipfilefile
# [scripts]
# server = "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "run", "server"]
```

Comment: Nice example, I found `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in your code very friendly. Thank you!

Comment: You have described how to wget instantclient for linux. Can you suggest the address for windows. I didn't get it

Comment: You deserve a medal tks

Comment: How would I reference the library in my code? At the moment I use cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir_inst) with lib_dir_inst being the location of the library, but with the procedure above I do not know the version of the library, so the path is unknown. Do I even need to use cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client?

Answer (score 18):

The latest release of the Python driver for Oracle got renamed to python-oracledb and is now a 'thin' driver by default. **It does not need Instant Client** - it's optional.  See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a). The Dockerfile can simply be like:

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

RUN python -m pip install oracledb
```

If you want the option to use the 'Thick' mode of python-oracledb, then you could use a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig

RUN python -m pip install oracledb
```

Oracle has Python cx_Oracle Dockerfiles at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers and cx_Oracle containers at https://github.com/orgs/oracle/packages

There is a two-part blog post series [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1) that shows various ways to install.  Also there is an Oracle webcast recording discussing cx_Oracle and Docker [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:551:::NO:RP,551:P551_CLASS_ID:6632&cs=18BE804CCFDC91F33951D7F141508CA25).

If you are still using the cx_Oracle namespace, you always need to install Instant Client so a solution is to use:

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1

WORKDIR /opt/oracle
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig
RUN python -m pip install cx_Oracle
```

If you use a different base image you may need to explicitly install wget and unzip.