# docker run error : DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python-3.x, docker, cx-oracle

I am trying to dockerize a very simple python application with Oracle database connection and execute it on Docker. This application is executing fine on my local machine.

I was successfully able to build this application but getting an error while executing it on Docker.

***DockerFile:***

```
FROM python:3

ADD File.py /

RUN pip install cx_Oracle
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install openpyxl

CMD [ "python", "./File.py" ]
```

***File.py:***

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

#creating database connection
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('dev-tr01.com', '1222', service_name='ast041.com')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'usr', password='3451', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()

query ='SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ROWNUM <10'
result = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
result.to_excel("batchtable.xlsx")

conn.close()
```

***Error:***

> docker run python_batchdriver:latest
>
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle release (renamed to python-oracledb).  This doesn't necessarily need Instant Client, which makes installation a lot easier.  See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).**

For cx_Oracle, you need to install Oracle Instant Client libraries too. See the [cx_Oracle installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-linux).

There are various ways to automate installation in Docker.  One example is:

```
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd instantclient* && \
    rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

You will also need the libaio or libaio1 package.

See [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Also see [Install Oracle Instant client into Docker container for Python cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992954/install-oracle-instant-client-into-docker-container-for-python-cx-oracle/59017157#59017157)
Note that the steps may be different if you are not using a Debian-based Linux distribution.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how are you able to use an asterisk in your Dockerfile? Whenever I use the code you have there, the build fails.

Comment: Works for me!  I expect I was using Podman.  I've also seen other people copy that syntax and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Debian based docker image needs a oracle instant client. You can download it manually and copy it to your docker image. A dependency "libaio1" is also required.

Add the below line in your docker file.

#### DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3

# Installing Oracle instant client
WORKDIR    /opt/oracle

# Install dependency
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1

# if extracted file is in current directory named "instantclient_11_2"
# For me instantclient_11_2 for Oracle9i, 10g
# copy it to /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

COPY instantclient_11_2 /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

# Linking instant client and cleanup
RUN cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
    && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci \
    && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
    && ldconfig

# Rest is same as yours
ADD File.py /

# To support instantclient_11_2 I used below commented line
# RUN pip install cx-Oracle==7.3.0

RUN pip install cx_Oracle
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install openpyxl

CMD [ "python", "./File.py" ]
```

Comment: You can use the latest cx_Oracle release with 11.2 client libraries, so there is no need to stay with 7.3.  Also you should plan to upgrade to the very latest release, which was renamed to 'python-oracledb', see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  To connect to your older databases you'll still need to use Instant Client with it.