# Ubuntu 20.04 Dockerfile getting a E: Unable to locate package yum error

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile, yum, oracleclient

My goal is to run this from a Dockerfile (which is basically setting up an Oracle client):

```
RUN  yum -y install /tmp/oracle-instantclient*.rpm && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
     rm -f /tmp/oracle-instantclient*.rpm && \
     echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient12.2.conf && \
     ldconfig
```

The problem is - I do not seem to have access to "yum". As of result, I try to add it as seen below.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN apt-get -y install curl
# Pick up some Python3 dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        yum \                   <------ Having a problem with "yum"
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libpng-dev \

[... snip ...]
```

When running docker-compose build, I get the following error:
E: Unable to locate package yum

It seems like yum was in earlier versions of Ubuntu (ex: Ubuntu 16) but it is not in Ubuntu 20(?) - or - am I missing something. If yum is not in Ubuntu 20, how can it be added?

TIA

Comment: Without being an expert here my suspicition is that you need to use other package manager in case of Ubuntu. Yum is a package manager for Red Hat. i guess this Docker image is based on an Oracle provided image. Oracle Linux is based on Red Hat. Maybe you need to use apt instead of yum

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had considered that - it was just all of the development I had done took place under Ubuntu. It seemed that the 16.x version of Ubuntu had Yum (without having to do anything special to install it). Was hoping for the same with Ubuntu 20.04. So, it seems I have some decisions to make - thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yum is only supported within the Centos Distribution,

If you are using Ubuntu (which your base image is), you must use apt for all package management operations within the Dockerfile

---

If you can only get the RPM files for the 'oracle-instantclient' package, as a **workaround** you can include the following in your dockerfile:

1. Install the 'Alien' package (converts between .rpm and .deb files):

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

2. Fetch the RPM file

```
wget [repository address]/package_name.rpm
```

3. Use Alien to do the file conversion:

```
sudo alien package_name.rpm
```

4. Install the .deb file using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the various ways to install Instant Client in Docker are discussed in [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1):

For example:

```
WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libaio1 unzip wget
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd instantclient* && \
    rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any answers but I found a hint here:
[Install Oracle Instant client into Docker container for Python cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992954/install-oracle-instant-client-into-docker-container-for-python-cx-oracle)

What worked for me was adding the following to the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR    /opt/oracle
RUN        apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip \
            && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
            && cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
            && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf \
            && ldconfig

# add instant client to path
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1
```

Regards.