# apk not found error while changing to node-buster from Alpine base image

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I have changed my image in docker from Alpine base image to node:14.16-buster, While running the code I am getting 'apk not found' error.

Sharing the codes snippet :

```
FROM node:14.16-buster

# ========= steps for Oracle instant client installation (start) ===============
RUN apk --no-cache add libaio libnsl libc6-compat curl && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -o instantclient-basiclite.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -SL && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
    mv instantclient*/ /usr/lib/instantclient && \
    rm instantclient-basiclite.zip
```

Can you please help here, what do I need to change?

Comment: Maybe I am not able to find it, but can community users point me to the link of this 14.16-buster image on docker hub.

Comment: There you go: https://hub.docker.com/layers/Node/library/node/14.16-buster/images/sha256-24361e7440d0d15268b2d7a664ce1a275c04d9a08eeca69f954772a5cef71da1?context=explore

Comment: Look the node-oracledb on Buster example in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you're changing your base image from Alpine based to Debian based.

Debian based Linux distributions use `apt` as their package manager (Alpine uses `apk`).

That is the reason why you get `apk not found`. Use `apt install`, but also keep in mind that the package names could differ and you might need to look that up. After all, `apt` is a different piece of software with it's own capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Buster images are based on the Debian version.

It doesn't support the **APK** default package manger is **APT**

For example you can do :

```
FROM node:15.14.0-buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      curl \
      jq \
      git \
      wget \
      openssl \
      bash \
      tar \
      net-tools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /app && \
    chown node:node /app
```

`APK` is part of the Linux alpine version you have to change the base version if you want to use the `APK`.

Answer (score 1):

The `buster` node images are Debian based. `buster` is the release name for Debian 10 (11 will be `bullseye`).

Debian uses [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) for packaging. [`apt-get`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) can be used from scripts

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libaio1 curl
```

libnsl2 is not available in [Buster](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libnsl-dev), but you [might not need it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869379/1318694)