# How to solve "Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library" erro that i am getting when try to run docker-compose

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

I am trying to dockerize a node application with a remote oracle database, trying to connect just using typeorm data-source, eveything works fine running local "npm start" but when i run docker-compose i get: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library error.

I am using Windows SO, already tried use linux oracle image but i not even get oracle to run.

```
FROM node:16 AS Development
 
ENV NODE_ENV=development
ENV CONNECT_STRING_DEV="dev=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ******)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ********)))"

WORKDIR /proj-inove/server

COPY package*.json /proj-inove/server
COPY yarn.lock /proj-inove/server

RUN npm install

RUN npm rebuild oracledb
# copia tudo e coloca na pasta raiz WORKDIR
COPY . /proj-inove/server

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/216000/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && rm -f instantclient-basic-windows.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *mql1* *ipc1* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig

WORKDIR /opt/oracle/instantclient*

COPY . /proj-inove/server/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release

WORKDIR /proj-inove/server/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/network/admin

RUN echo ${CONNECT_STRING_DEV} > tnsnames.ora

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The container is Linux, so install the Linux version of Instant Client, not the Windows version.

See answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017157/4799035 for details.  It also links to a two-part blog post series [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1) that shows various ways to install.

Comment: I tried to install for this tutorial before i think and when i try to install linux images i get this error "serverinove exited with code 0" when initiating server.

Comment: When you have more information about that, you could open a new SO question.