# How to connect Apache Superset with Oracle using Docker

Tags: dockerfile, cx-oracle, apache-superset, python-oracledb

I installed `cx_oracle` in my python Docker container. When connecting to Oracle db I get this error:

```
An error occurred while creating databases: (builtins.NoneType) None
[SQL: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

Oracle database connection with Docker and execute the python Oracle connection code in docker terminal:

```py
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('admin/12345678@database-1.pppppppppp.oo-kailsam-0.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/DATABASE')
cur = connection.cursor()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyc3P.png)

Answer (score 2):

According to your error messages, you're likely missing the Oracle client libraries [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html).
The new major Python cx_Oracle driver release is available as [`python-oracledb`](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) and doesn't need the Oracle client libraries.

To install and use python-oracledb: `python -m pip install oracledb`

Test your connection to Oracle with:

```py
import oracledb
    
connection = oracledb.connect(user='scott', password=secretpw, dsn='localhost/oraclepdb1')
    
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  for row in cursor.execute('select * from dual'):
    print(row)
```

More info here: [Install Oracle Instant client into Docker container for Python cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017157/22257868)

Comment: have tested this is working fine but i am working in apache superset , apache superset has taken only cx_oracle library , have tested with oracle cloud database using cx_oracle libraries , same code and configuration not working in docker.

thanks

Comment: Start by reading the documentation at the link in the DPI-1047 error message. Or read [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python).